# Prevent multiple AJAX calls to the same url within timeframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an app which wants to get info about every marker on a map.

Each marker has a class, such as "car" or "pedestrian".

The app makes (via jQuery) a `getJSON` call to "http://myserver/info/".

However, since multiple markers may have the same class, the server could end up getting hit with many requests.

Accordingly, I'd like to pool requests which occur within a specified time frame (maybe 5 seconds or so) so that only one request is made, but each calling instance of `getJSON` is unaware of it.

My thought is to wrap `getJSON` in another function which stores the URLS in a hashmap/dictionary and stores up promises for each requester. When data is returned, the promises are fulfilled.

I ask, is there a standard way of doing this (debouncing an AJAX request, as it were)?

Comment: Do you want to fire the first request immediately, and then delay/unite further ones, or do you want to open a timeslot on the first call that waits for further calls before firing?

Comment: @Bergi, I'd prefer to send the first request immediately.

Comment: Is queuing them better or synchronizing similar requests within a specific timeframe better? (I guess I don't understand why you'd want to proceed with 3 requests to the same endpoint if they (presumably) will have the same result).

Comment: @BradChristie, I see this as being a kind of unobtrusive way of synchronizing the requests. Most of the codebase should be unaware that synchronization is happening at all.

Comment: @Richard: Not very elegant, but does hide the implementation from the usage (hijacks `$.getJSON`): http://jsfiddle.net/ajtbdxt7/ Any request after the initial gets a reference to the first (you'll see "coupe" and "bob" items come in together since they refer to the same promise).

Answer (score 2):

I created something (in 25 minutes ^^) that might help you; it's a Timeout manager:

```
var requestsPool = {
    requests: {}, //list of urls
    timeout: 5000, //In milliseconds
    add: function(url) {
        if(requestsPool.exists(url)) return false; //check if url is already present in the pool
        requestsPool.requests[url] = setTimeout(function(u) {
            requestsPool.remove(u);
        }.bind(this, url), requestsPool.timeout); //Defining the timeout
        return true;
    },
    exists: function(url) {
        return requestsPool.requests[url]; //Return the Timeout ID if present or undefined
    },
    remove: function(url) {
        return delete requestsPool.requests[url]; //return true almost always @link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete
    },
    cancel: function(url) {
        clearTimeout(requestsPool.requests[url]); //cancel the timeout
        return requestsPool.remove(url); //remove the url form the pool
    }
}

$(anchor).click(function() {
    if(requestsPool.exists(anchor.href)) {
        // If cooldown is present
    } else {
        $.getJSON(anchor.href, function(data) {
            requestsPool.add(anchor.href);
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this would solve things. If requests take a while to return, many requests will be made before we can take advantage of the requestPool.

Comment: You can still change where the `requestsPool.add` call is made. you can even add an `update` method to `requestsPool` which cancel then re-add an url

Answer (score 2):

> My thought is to wrap `getJSON` in another function which stores the URLS in a hashmap/dictionary and stores up promises for each requester

Yes, that's a good idea. It might look like this:

```
var debouncedGet = (function() {
    var pool = {};
    return function get(url) {
        if (!pool[url]) {
            pool[url] = $.getJSON(url);
            setTimeout(function() {
                pool[url] = null;
            }, 5000); // you might want to move this into a `pool[url].always(…)` callback
                      // so the timer starts when the request returned
         }
         return pool[url];
     };
 }());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my bid:

```
(function(window,$,undefined){
    'use strict';

    var cache = {},
        timeout = 5e3;

    // Use like traditional $.getJSON
    $.getJSON = function(url,data,callback){
        if ($.isFunction(data)){
            callback = data;
            data = undefined;
        }

        // Establish a cache key so we can re-reference existing
        // requests to subsequent ones (within the timeout window).
        var cacheKey = url;
        if (cache[cacheKey]){
            // This is an existing request; Simple add the callback
            // onto the promise and return it.
            return cache[cacheKey].done(callback);
        } else {
            // This is a new request. Build up a new request,
            // attach the callback to the promise, and also add
            // a couple cleanup methods for disposing the cache
            // when appropriate.
            cache[cacheKey] = $.ajax($.extend({
                url: url,
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: data,
            }, $.isPlainObject(url) && url))
            .done(callback)
            .always(function(){
                delete cache[cacheKey];
            });
            setTimeout(function(){
                // TODO: Probbaly want to store a reference to
                // this timeout and clear it in the .always (to
                // avoid race condition between .always firing
                // and new request coming in but not returning yet)
                cache[cacheKey] && delete cache[cacheKey];
            }, timeout);
            return cache[cacheKey];
        }
    };
})(window,jQuery);
```

And, FWIW, a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ajtbdxt7/